# Running sudo su command with privileges in java

Tags: java, bash, unix

Requirement is to run the following unix command `sudo su - fwt****app` in java.

Below is my code:

```
Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");

String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash","-c","echo password| sudo -S -p su - fwt***app; ls"};

((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(cmd.toString());

InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();

OutputStream out=channel.getOutputStream();

((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

channel.connect();

out.write(("Password"+"\n").getBytes()); 

out.flush();
```

Have tried other method as well, which is `((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(sudo -S -p su - fwt***app)`, it didn't worked.

I have tried switching to other user by using command 
su - fwtveguiapp
Password:
But got response as - su: Sorry
It needs to run using both sudo and su commands.
As both sudo and su commands are required I am getting a syntax error in sudo command.                                                                     Other references helps only with sudo command hence they were not helpful in my case.

Comment: I have checked the above solution it didn't worked for me as the above code requires both sudo and su command to be used together

Comment: And how does that make it not work?

Comment: I get the below error on executing the following command in java :          sudo -S -p su - fwtveguiapp;                                                                       
Error :  sudo: '-' requires an argument
usage: sudo -K | -L | -V | -h | -k | -l | -v
usage: sudo [-HPSb] [-p prompt] [-u username|#uid] [-g group|#gid]
{ -e file [...] | -i | -s | <command> }

Comment: You are specifying the option `-p su` to `sudo` where apparently your intent is something else.  Check the manual page when you use options.

Comment: the requirement is to execute sudo su - fwt****pp command, which requires password using java. Hence I have used sudo -S -p su - fwt**app command which will prompt for password but it turn outs to be a wrong syntax. Could there be some other way?

Comment: Read this slowly. The `-p` option to `sudo` takes a parameter.  You are not running `su`, you are specifying `su` as the string to use as the prompt for `sudo` and the stuff after it is also being interpreted as options to `sudo`, not to `su`

Comment: Opening the channel as shell and using ps.println("sudo su - fwtveguiapp"); getting connected; thanx :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to switch to root or other user.

But what you can do is running a process with sudo. I think you need to provide each argument as String in the cmd[]

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash","-c","sudo", "fwt***app"};
```

And if you have multiple commands, then you need to execute each command separately

Comment: Coud you explain me in more detail. It would be great help

Comment: How would you provide authentication?